# Shell Script sed to search for 2 different matches and replace it with different values in loop

Tags: shell, for-loop, sed

In shell script i am unable to find solution for below:
I have a file.txt generated as below , whose values are not fixed

```
    "string1","string2"
    "string4","string5"
    "string6","string9"
    "string10","string11"
```

I have another file:

```
 <abc><cde>var_1</cde><efg>var_2</efg></abc>
```

I need to generate output file as below

```
<abc><cde>string1</cde><efg>string2</efg></abc>
<abc><cde>string4</cde><efg>string5</efg></abc>
<abc><cde>string6</cde><efg>string9</efg></abc>
<abc><cde>string10</cde><efg>string11</efg></abc>
```

Comment: Does `file.txt` have leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: no leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` command would do that

```
sed 's#"\([^"]*\)","\([^"]*\)"#<abc><cde>\1</cde><efg>\2</efg></abc>#' file.txt
```

What is going on here.

First we use the `s#pattern#replacement#` subcommand to replace every line of the input file that matches the `pattern` with the `replacement` string.

Let's look at the `pattern` first. The pattern is `"\([^"]*\)","\([^"]*\)"`. It says

1. Look for a quote character `"` in the input
2. select all symbols up to the next quote character as the first substitution expression this is expressed as `\([^"]*\)` where the expression in brackets `\(...\)` is the pattern for the substitution expression. The pattern is `[^"]*` which means take zero or more characters apart from `"`.
3. ignore the next `","` and select the second substitution expression up to the next quote character.

We identified the substrings in quotes as replacement text for the first and the second substitution expression referred to as `\1` and `\2` respectively.

Now for the `replacement`. It is taken literally with the exception of `\1` and `\2` that are replaced with the first and second substitution expression identified when matching the pattern.

Comment: HI Dmitri, Can you explain how this works or share me a link to read and understand the pattern is identified by script...it sure worked though

Comment: @avinashRudra updated the post with more details. For more info please read the [Info documentation for GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: Yeah got it thanks a lot, i was playing around after your inputs trying to learn more.

But if i change my input to "string1",string2 , i.e without " for the 2nd string.
with sed as
sed 's#"\([^"]*\)",\(*\)#<abc><cde>\1</cde><efg>\2</efg></abc>#' file.txt

the above failed

Comment: Yeah got it thanks a lot, i was playing around after your inputs trying to learn more.

But if i change my input to `"string1",string2` i.e without `"` for the 2nd string.
with sed as
`sed 's#"\([^"]*\)",\(*\)#<abc><cde>\1</cde><efg>\2</efg></abc>#' file.txt`

the above failed

Comment: @avinashRudra  Try this: `sed 's#"\([^"]*\)",\(.*\)#<abc><cde>\1</cde><efg>\2</efg></abc>#' file.txt`. Note the dot in the second bracketed expression as in regex the star `*` is an operator applied to the preceding pattern and the dot is a pattern to match any single character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/cat anotherFile/e;x};G
        s/.*"(.*)","(.*)".*\n(.*)var_1(.*)var_2/\3\1\4\2/' txtFile
```

Store `anotherFile` in the hold space on the first line only.

Append `anotherFile` to each line of `txtFile` and using pattern matching format the result.